# Snowflake sql - how to get the total subscriber based on gained/lost columns for each day and id?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the below sample of my table, that has thousands of ids and a row for each day for each id, I also have a subscriber_gained and subscriber_lost for each day/id. Is there a way to calculate how many followers I have for each day with this amount if data?

| metrics_date | id | subscriber_lost | subscriber_gained |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-03 | 3343 | 54 | 37 |
| 2022-12-02 | 3343 | 29 | 27 |
| 2022-12-03 | 1223 | 44 | 26 |
| 2022-12-02 | 1223 | 21 | 36 |

I want to have a query that shows the running total for that day for that id:

| metrics_date | id | subscriber_lost | subscriber_gained | number_of_visitors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-03 | 3343 | 54 | 37 | 1209 |
| 2022-12-02 | 3343 | 29 | 27 | 1226 |
| 2022-12-03 | 1223 | 44 | 26 | 3521 |
| 2022-12-02 | 1223 | 21 | 36 | 3539 |

I've tried this query but the total is off :

```
select 
    METRICS_DATE,
    channel_id,
    number_of_visitors,
    case 
        when lag(number_of_visitors) over(order by METRICS_DATE) is null 
            then number_of_visitors
        when lag(number_of_visitors) over(order by METRICS_DATE) < number_of_visitors
            then number_of_visitors - lag(number_of_visitors) over(order by METRICS_DATE)
        else 0
    end subscribers_gained,
    case when lag(number_of_visitors) over(order by METRICS_DATE) > number_of_visitors
            then lag(number_of_visitors) over(order by METRICS_DATE) - number_of_visitors
        else 0
    end subscribers_lost
from (
    select METRICS_DATE,
    channel_id,
    count(*) number_of_visitors 
    from you.p_content_owner_basic_a3_you
    where channel_id = '3343'
    group by METRICS_DATE,
    channel_id
) t
order by METRICS_DATE desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so with some data in a CTE for the simplicity of it:

```
with data(metrics_date, id, subscriber_lost, subscriber_gained) as (
    select * from values

    ('2022-12-03'::date, 3343, 54,   37),
    ('2022-12-02'::date, 3343, 29,   27),
    
    ('2022-12-03'::date, 1223, 44,   26),
    ('2022-12-02'::date, 1223, 21,   36),
    
    ('2022-12-01'::date, 9999, 0,    10),
    ('2022-12-02'::date, 9999, 5,    10),
    ('2022-12-03'::date, 9999, 15,   10),
    ('2022-12-04'::date, 9999, 10,   10)
)
```

what you are want is to subtract the two [window frame](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html#label-window-frames) [SUM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/sum.html)'s of the two partials:

```
select
    d.*
    ,sum(d.subscriber_gained) over ( partition by d.id order by d.metrics_date) - 
    sum(d.subscriber_lost) over ( partition by d.id order by d.metrics_date) as number_of_visitors
from data as d
order by 2,1;
```

which can also be express as the sum of the difference.

```
select
    d.*
    ,sum(d.subscriber_gained - d.subscriber_lost) over ( partition by d.id order by d.metrics_date) as number_of_visitors
from data as d
order by 2,1;
```

| METRICS_DATE | ID | SUBSCRIBER_LOST | SUBSCRIBER_GAINED | NUMBER_OF_VISITORS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-02 | 1223 | 21 | 36 | 15 |
| 2022-12-03 | 1223 | 44 | 26 | -3 |
| 2022-12-02 | 3343 | 29 | 27 | -2 |
| 2022-12-03 | 3343 | 54 | 37 | -19 |
| 2022-12-01 | 9999 | 0 | 10 | 10 |
| 2022-12-02 | 9999 | 5 | 10 | 15 |
| 2022-12-03 | 9999 | 15 | 10 | 10 |
| 2022-12-04 | 9999 | 10 | 10 | 10 |

### Percentage change

```
select
    d.*
    ,d.subscriber_gained - d.subscriber_lost as change
    ,sum(change) over ( partition by d.id order by d.metrics_date) as number_of_visitors
    ,round(div0(change, number_of_visitors+change) *100,1) as before_percent_change
    ,round(div0(change, number_of_visitors) *100,1) as after_percent_change
from data as d
order by 2,1;
```

gives:

| METRICS_DATE | ID | SUBSCRIBER_LOST | SUBSCRIBER_GAINED | CHANGE | NUMBER_OF_VISITORS | BEFORE_PERCENT_CHANGE | AFTER_PERCENT_CHANGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-02 | 1223 | 21 | 36 | 15 | 15 | 50 | 100 |
| 2022-12-03 | 1223 | 44 | 26 | -18 | -3 | 85.7 | 600 |
| 2022-12-02 | 3343 | 29 | 27 | -2 | -2 | 50 | 100 |
| 2022-12-03 | 3343 | 54 | 37 | -17 | -19 | 47.2 | 89.5 |
| 2022-12-01 | 9999 | 0 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 50 | 100 |
| 2022-12-02 | 9999 | 5 | 10 | 5 | 15 | 25 | 33.3 |
| 2022-12-03 | 9999 | 15 | 10 | -5 | 10 | -100 | -50 |
| 2022-12-04 | 9999 | 10 | 10 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: thanks, is there a way to show add another column showing the percentage change for each day/id?

Comment: yes, the biggest question, do you want the divisor to be yesterdays total, or todays after the change total?

Comment: ```    ,round(div0(change, number_of_visitors+change) *100,1) as before_percent_change
    ,round(div0(change, number_of_visitors) *100,1) as after_percent_change
```

Comment: neat! I suppose we would want it todays after the change, thank you!

Comment: the before (yesterdays total) was wrong should use minus `-` not addition `+`

Comment: Simeon a question, is this something that could have been done using lag() as well, I tried with that but I couldn't get it working. Just curious, your answers work perfectly though!

Comment: the SUM part your base question is not solvable with LAG, as LAG provide a fix row offset, and accumulation you want arbitrary history, which is what SUM OVER allows.